# Test my android app in a custom display like a 7 " mdpi?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, scale, dpi

How can I test my android app in  custom displays like a 7" mdpi display or 10" hdpi display ? in eclipse only can test the predefined devices and when I try to put a custom dpi or screen size only the emulator display get scaled.

Thank you

** [Solved] I found the answer by myself, when you go to Android Virtual Device Manager there are 2 tabs in the second u can create custom devices

Comment: While I wouldn't make a habit of it, it's ok to answer your own question and accept it. This way, other people with the same issue will be able to benefit from your post.